# Would spacecraft suffer from fevers?

Tags: space, space-travel, spaceships, space-constructs, radiation

Spacecrafts produce a lot of heat, which must go somewhere if the inhabitants don't want to die. And in space, the only way to get rid of the heat is to radiate it away

One way of achieving this would be pipes, which wrap around the habitat and then go out into a large plane of snaked pipe which would be the radiator

This system seems like it would be hard to take down and maintain, especially on rockets, where mass is expensive and spare radiators would be ridiculous. And there is a lot that could go wrong: chunks of pipe-lining obstructing the pipe, unwanted chemistry making the fluid inefficient, or even some sort of meteoroid-algae growing on the radiators themselves

These problems will reduce the efficiency of the radiator, causing it to settle into a hotter equilibrium until serviced, sort of like a fever

The question is, are my premises realistic? Specifically the third premise, that radiators would be hard to service. On its face, it seems like it'd be hard to service something that'd always be on, but I'm no expert

Comment: "Space radiators" are **not** ridiculous, and they are most definitely not "a large plane of snakes pipe". Look at a [picture of the ISS](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:International_Space_Station_after_undocking_of_STS-132.jpg): the radiators are the white zig-zag panels. The way they work is that an ordinary cooling loop pumps heat from the inside of the spacecraft to the radiators, which, duh, radiate it into space. The [External Active Thermal Control System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_Active_Thermal_Control_System) of the ISS is "capable of rejecting up to 70 kW".

Comment: [Helium cooling in fusion power plants](https://inis.iaea.org/collection/NCLCollectionStore/_Public/26/039/26039608.pdf) (1994) (pdf warning)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, radiating panels would need to be outside, and therefore might be harder to fix. Also, the panels' efficiency in radiating heat can suffer in a variety of ways - dust, micrometeorites, stuff protruding in its 'view' (The panel will radiate in every direction, so if other stuff (like another ship, or just loose debris) is situated over it, the panel cannot radiate anymore, or only into those directions where it can still 'see' the cold sky, reducing its effectiveness).

But: a reduced efficiency of the panels will not cause a stable elevated temperature on the ship. Either the heat-pumps supplying the panel just raise the temperature of the panel, thus overcoming the degraded performance (power radiated goes by T^4), or, if the heatpumps are already at their upper limit, the ship suffers runaway heating, killing everyone.

Panel area will be in plentiful supply, because the ship cannot bet on every surface pointing into a good direction to get rid of heat (a nearby sun would shine on any exposed panel in that direction, rendering this panel useless for heat dissipation, planets also radiate heat, ...), and heat-pumps will usually be working far from their maximum, so the heat-death because of badly 'serviced' panels will be far off.

BUT: the panels *will* need to be serviced, and *their* temperature (not the temp of the whole ship), especially over time will tell the observer something about their efficiency/the current dissipated power. So seeing a ship with Panels 'glowing' (in the NIR), i.e. a 'fever', might be a good indicator that lots of power currently need to be dissipated (is a weapon spooling up?) or that the panels are bad.

So if the observer has some reason to know how much power is currently dissipated, the temperature of the panels tells them how taxed the radiative elements are.

'Servicing' those panels might constitute removing dust, repainting/resurfacing, or replacing, though I see no reason why an EVA should happen towards that goal, as all of that should be doable by remote control actuators in the age of daily spaceflight. EVAs being a thing nowadays is only because the sensor/actuator packages for the kind of sensory- and action-range that humans (even in bulky spacesuits) posess are still much bulkier than humans. This will change. -- But if it doesn't? Sure, then EVAs to hot panels will be dangerous. The suit needs to keep itself cool while being warmed by the panel occupying half of its world, the panels might leak something harmful to the suit, the reason for the degraded performance might still be ongoing (dust, micrometeorites, nearby debris, enemy action)

Answer (score 2):

### No.

Given the specs that you've laid out, it is simply not possible for the kind of cosmoship described to suffer from a fever.  Simply put, its physiology is not biological enough to suffer from the querried ailment.

A [fever](https://www.webmd.com/lung/what-is-a-fever#1) is a disruption in homeostasis, specifically, the physiological state a biological creature, be it planetaric or cosmic, suffers e.g. when it is invaded by some infectious organism.

Living cosmoships, of course, can suffer from fevers if they are not treated with a standard inoculation protocol during their lifetime and are not sufficiently monitored & treated while in space or at port. The medical department is responsible for keeping a stock of universal and specific [antipyretics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antipyretic) as well as common anti-invasive medications.

Your mechanical cosmoships can suffer from an analogous malaise. If the machine *overheats* due to an external cause such as a coolant leak, then it might be likened to a fever.

That said, your premises seem realistic enough: some kind of pipe based coolant system that transfers heat from the heat generating areas within to space without makes sense. Gunking it up or something preventing heat transfer growing on the outside also make sensible problems.

As for the key premise, any time something needs maintenance, it will be "hard to service". Plumbers, electricians, Starfleet engineers have been carping about how difficult it will be to fix a problem for myriads upon myriads. Especially if the problem with the radiating system in question is outside the confines of the vessel. Space suits, droids, perhaps an ancillary workshop shuttlecraft would have to be sent out to fix the problem.

**Conclusion:**  Your kind of spaceship can *overheat*, but it can not suffer from a *fever*.

Comment: Surely it's only a fever if it overheats from some *internal* cause, as in fighting infections; if it's an external cause, it's heatstroke.

Comment: @Cadence -- Both infectious agent and heatstroke are external causes! An internal cause would be a body's own reaction to something, like malignant hyperthermia. I only mentioned infection as a well known possibility.

Comment: I disagree with your premise. Depending on the musical tastes of its occupants, a spaceship can absolutely suffer from Saturday Night Fever

Comment: @nullpointer your comment is crass, irrelevant to the answer, and... made me snort my morning coffee through my nose. Low blow, dude, congratulations!

Answer (score 0):

> These problems will reduce the efficiency of the radiator, causing it to settle into a hotter equilibrium until serviced, sort of like a fever

Terminology aside, this will probably not be possible.

Here's the thing. To maintain an equilibrium temperature, the heat dumped out by the radiators must equal the heat generated by whatever internal sources there are.

If your radiators become less effective and you *don't* turn down your engines or reactor or pizza oven or whatever, then the temperature of the spacecraft will rise continuously, and the contents (eg. you) will cook.

The temperature inside your spaceship, then, can only rise above equilibrium in response to a *temporary* excess of heat generation, such as running the engines too hard or maybe operating weaponry. You then have to cool your jets and ease up on the trigger for a bit. There's a very small margin of error here, because meatbags are notoriously delicate.

In all other situations, the spacecraft will remain pleasantly temperate up until the point that it suddenly isn't and everyone dies.

> This system seems like it would be hard to take down and maintain, especially on rockets, where mass is expensive and spare radiators would be ridiculous. And there is a lot that could go wrong: chunks of pipe-lining obstructing the pipe, unwanted chemistry making the fluid inefficient, or even some sort of meteoroid-algae growing on the radiators themselves

There are many, *many* different kinds of radiator. Not all of them use a fluid to transfer heat. Not all of them are easy to maintain. The ones that are will likely be less efficient at dumping heat for a given size and mass of radiator.

Heat rejection is hideously difficult, and one of the many ways in which hard sci-fi restricts the awesomeness of spacecraft. You'd be well advised to do a bit of reading on the subject... Project Rho has [plenty of information on thhe subject](http://www.projectrho.com/public_html/rocket/heatrad.php).

Comment: since radiator efficiency increases with the fourth power of temperature differential, it could very well settle at a higher equilibrium.